# Replace left navigation button with custom button, then back

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a `UITableView` within an `UINavigationController`. On the right of the `UINavigationBar` I have an "Edit" button. When I tap this button, all the textfields in the table cells become activated so I can edit them. The right button changes to "Save".

I'd now like the left "back" button of the `UINavigationController` to be replaced by a "Cancel" button which when I tap doesn't bring me back to the previous `UIViewController`, but just cancels editing mode.

When I tap "Save" the "Cancel" button should be changed back to the usual `UINavigationController` back button. Is there any easy way to do this? I tried accessing `[[self navigationItem] leftBarButtonItem]`. This works for the right button, but not the left one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom back button for NavigationController for every screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516839/custom-back-button-for-navigationcontroller-for-every-screen)

Comment: That is not an appropriate duplicate. This question is not about creating a custom back button. This question is about temporarily replacing the back button with another button.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `leftBarButtonItem` to your Cancel button. At the appropriate time, set the `leftBarButtonItem` to `nil` to remove your Cancel button. This will automatically restore the original back button that was in place before you added the Cancel button.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the leftBarButtonItem is a "BackButton", which is set on the UIView(Controller) you used to navigate to the current View.

You can hide the BackButton following the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453519/how-to-hide-the-back-button-in-uinavigationcontroller). This should be done, since you cannot change it's behavior.

I believe you are then able to [use the leftBarButtonItem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3937432/410699).

Answer (score 0):

See [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739599/disabling-back-button-and-put-cancel-button-in-navigation-view-controller-lik).

Then make sure you declare the cancel method similar to this.

```
(void)cancel:(id)sender {
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```